# Template parameters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates

I would like to use a `Filename` class that only allows itself to be constructed with a certain extension. I can't just use the constructor (e.g. FileName(".txt"), because I want my class to be used in function annotations, e.g.

```
def my_func( file_name : FileName[".txt"] ): . . .
```

I can see inbuilt types such as the type-hint classes get around this issue using templates:

```
List[T]
Union[T, U]
Optional[T]` # inherits Union[T, None`]
```

And I can obtain these parameters via, e.g. `my_union.__union_args__`.

Is it possible to create my own class that takes template parameters?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Same as any of the other annotations (List, Union, Optional, Dict, etc) in the standard library (though in my case I've found almost everything is `str`, hence my request). Type annotations are used as a form of documentation to the programmer, a hint to a calling program, or for use with a verification tool. I think the reasons are too long to get into here, but check out https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484 -- or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming) for the wider issue.

Comment: I'm well aware of type hinting. That's why I'm asking why you want to do this. What's so special for a filename other than it's an `str`?

Comment: What you're after (restricting the extention from what I understand) isn't the job of types, that's a runtime requirement you'll need to enforce yourself in code.

Comment: My calling library uses the annotations to present the GUI and assert the data provided by the user is correct. In terms of validating filenames, C++'s boost provides some use cases in their docs for their `Path` class: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/filesystem/doc/path.htm

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (eventually). I case anyone else is interested, you just need to define **get_item** on the metaclass:

```
def __getitem__( self, item ):
    return self.__class__( self.__name__,
                           (self,) + self.__bases__,
                           dict( self.__dict__ ),
                           item = item )
```

Then `item` can be anything you want (an extension, a type, etc.)

Quite nicely, the IDE (I'm using PyCharm) seems to have no problem picking up any extra attributes when it parses the annotations.